# Pushing files directly to bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

Can i push the files directly to bitbucket without creating a local repository in my machine. I have a company laptop, in which i am not authorized to install any additional softwares. Whenever i make changes in my file, i would like to push it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can’t. Git is a decentralized version control system and to push something in it, you need a repository to push from—and more importantly the software to actually do this. Unfortunately Bitbucket also does allow editing files directly in the browser (unlike GitHub), so you will have to do it manually in some way.

If you are using Windows, you could give [PortableGit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list) a try. It’s essentially the same except that you do not need to install it.

Another option would be to choose some solution that uses [libgit2](http://libgit2.github.com/) directly (instead of the command line) and comes also bundled with it.

Answer (score 2):

Git doesn't technically require installation, it's just a collection of commandline tools that make use of environment variables.

There is a [portable version](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/detail?name=PortableGit-1.8.0-preview20121022.7z&can=2&q=) available that you can run without any installation being required.

Another option to consider is using an online editor such as [Cloud9](http://c9.io) which allows you to clone repositories in the cloud, make changes and push back (see [this post](http://support.cloud9ide.com/entries/20754818-push-your-git-cloud9-project-to-bitbucket)).

Comment: I didn't know about the Cloud9 option. +1 (an alternative to my simple answer)

Answer (score 2):

No.
Only GitHub would allow to modify a file from the GitHub web interface.
(as illustrated in "[Creating files on GitHub](https://github.com/blog/1327-creating-files-on-github)")

Even if you have Git installed (and there is a portable version), you would still need a local clone in order to push.